# VBA --- How to change UserForm properties name dynamically based on user input --- Template Literal

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to change **$$$** based on the user's input. I know their data type isn't a string, so I can't use string concatenation (e.g. "frm_" & "**$$$**" & ".lst_") or regular expression to replace **$$$** into different name/variable/string. I am looking for a way like Template Literal in JavaScript (**${}**). Is there a similar way in VBA? Thanks.

```
If frm_$$$.lst_$$$_ABCDE.ListCount > 0 Then
      frm_$$$.lbl_$$$_ACE.Caption = "Lorem ipsum: " & frm_$$$*.lst_$$$_ABCDE.ListCount
ElseIf frm_$$$.lst_$$$_ABCDE.ListCount = 0 Then
      frm_$$$.lbl_TH_centercount.Caption = "Lorem ipsumt: 0"
      frm_$$$.cmd_$$$_Save.Enabled = False
      frm_$$$.cmd_$$$_Next.Enabled = False
End If
```

I expect the If/ElseIf condition is changed based on the user's input from above to below.

If the user's input is **ABC** then,

```
If frm_ABC.lst_ABC_ABCDE.ListCount > 0 Then
      frm_ABC.lbl_ABC_ACE.Caption = "Lorem ipsum: " & frm_ABC.lst_ABC_ABCDE.ListCount
ElseIf frm_ABC.lst_ABC_ABCDE.ListCount = 0 Then
      frm_ABC.lbl_TH_centercount.Caption = "Lorem ipsumt: 0"
      frm_ABC.cmd_ABC_Save.Enabled = False
      frm_ABC.cmd_ABC_Next.Enabled = False
End If
```

Comment: VBA doesn't work that way.  What is `frm_$$$` ?  A userform? Where is this code located?  Is the eventual form already open?  More details about your exact use case would be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

What about using [CStr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions) to convert the user input to a string? You could then define a variable as the converted user input and use the variable for string concatenation.